# How to split file with students into array using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file which looks like:

```
*students.txt*
student_a OS 20
student_a EN 30
student_b OS -
student_c OS -
student_c EN 20
```

And i want to split it into array:

```
student    avarage maximum
student_a  25      EN 30
student_b  -       -
student_c  20      EN 20
```

How i can do this using only AWK script?

For now I have only:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN {
    while ((getline line < file) > 0) {
        print line;
    }
    close(file)
}
END {}
```

After this i do not know how to split it.

Comment: Start by writing an awk script.  If you have problems, post the script and the outcome here.  Ask specific questions and you're more likely to get help.

Comment: I've added some code that i have. Thank you

Comment: Where does that `average` 25 come from? Why does `EN` string appear in the desired output and why does `OS` string not? What do you mean with `split`?

Comment: @Jdamian OS = `20` and EN = `30`, so average is `25`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear how you handle the missing values but this seems to match your output.

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'maxValue[$1]<$3{maxValue[$1]=$3; maxName[$1]=$2}
                        ($3+0==$3){sum[$1]+=$3; count[$1]++} 
                               END{print "student","average","maximum"; 
                                   for(k in maxValue) 
                                      print k, 
                                            count[k]?sum[k]/count[k]:"-",
                                            maxName[k]" "maxValue[k]}' file | 
  column -t -s$'\t'

student    average  maximum
student_a  25       EN 30
student_b  -        OS -
student_c  20       EN 20
```

**Explanation**

compute max value and assign corresponding name for third field keyed by the first field (i.e. a max value/name pair for each distinct first field).  For numerical values (`$3+0==$3` is the test for numerical value) aggregate sum and counts.  When done print header and for each key, print key average (if exists) and max name/value pair.

format with `column -t` to align tabbed fields of different lengths.

**UPDATE** 
To get the exact output match, make this change in the last print argument

```
.. print ..., count[k]?maxName[k]" "maxValue[k]:"-"}' 

student    average  maximum
student_a  25       EN 30
student_b  -        -
student_c  20       EN 20
```

Comment: Better, but that indention really makes no sense.